# Data lost after shutting down hadoop HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Hi I'm learning hadoop and I have a simple dumb question: After I shut down HDFS(by calling hadoop_home/sbin/stop-dfs.sh), is the data on HDFS lost or can I get it back?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Data wouldn't be lost if you stop HDFS, provided you store the data of NameNode and DataNode's in a persistent locations specified using the properties:

- `dfs.namenode.name.dir` -> Determines where on the local filesystem the DFS name node should store the name table(fsimage). If this is a comma-delimited list of directories then the name table is replicated in all of the directories, for redundancy. Default value: `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/name`
- `dfs.datanode.data.dir` -> Determines where on the local filesystem an DFS data node should store its blocks. If this is a comma-delimited list of directories, then data will be stored in all named directories, typically on different devices. Directories that do not exist are ignored. Default value: `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data`

As you could see, the default values for both properties point to `${hadoop.tmp.dir}` which by default is `/tmp`. You might already know that the data in `/tmp` in Unix based systems get's cleared on reboot's.

So, if you would specify dir location's other than `/tmp` then Hadoop HDFS daemons on reboot would be able to read back the data and hence no data loss even on cluster restart's.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are not deleting metadata of your data stored in HDFS and this you can achieve simply if you are keeping `dfs.namenode.name.dir` and `dfs.datanode.data.dir` untouced, means not deleting path present in these tags which present in your `hdfs-site.xml` file.