# How to copy files into HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to start a hadoop single node cluster on my local machine. I have configured the following files according to https://amodernstory.com/2014/09/23/installing-hadoop-on-mac-osx-yosemite/: hadoop-env.sh, core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml. When I run the script `start-dfs.sh` and then the command `jps` (right after running `start-dfs.sh`) I see that the datanode is up and running:

```
15735 Jps
15548 DataNode
15660 SecondaryNameNode
15453 NameNode
```

A few seconds later, I re-run the command `jps` and I see that the datanode is not running. Why? How to resolve this?

After that I run the script `start-yarn.sh` and then the command `jps`. I see this:

```
15955 NodeManager
16011 Jps
15660 SecondaryNameNode
15453 NameNode
15854 ResourceManager
```

My ultimate aim is to copy files into the HDFS from my local filesystem. For doing so, I run the command `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /source-file-path/filename /destination-file-path/`. I get the following error:

```
17/07/10 17:09:00 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /pay/txnlinking/redshift.yml._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2496)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:828)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:506)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:788)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2455)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:440)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:335)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:658)
copyFromLocal: File /pay/txnlinking/redshift.yml._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

How to avoid the above error and copy files into the HDFS?

P.S: I created the destination path folders in HDFS explicitly before doing the copy.

Comment: Have you checked the datanode logs?

Comment: This error tells you that `file could only be replicated to 0 nodes` which means you have no running datanodes and hdfs is not started properly. Something might be wrong with your configs or network topology (e.g. namenode cannot connect datanode). Check logs first of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First delete the contents of the `hadoop.tmp.dir` folder that you specified in core-site.xml. Then do a namenode format using `hdfs namenode -format`. Your datanode should be up and running properly after which all the copy operations will be successfully executed.

Comment: Is your default hadoop directory in tmp if so you should change it otherwise u will lose the hdfs every time you restart

Comment: I believe it is because I do lose the files in HDFS every time I restart. I blindly used the configs that were specified in the article I shared in my question. But now I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28379125/2531472) to avoid that from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

then stop all services using

```
stop-all.sh
```

then restart all services using

```
start-all.sh
```

start-all.sh and stop-all.sh are deprecated use start-dfs.sh and stop-dfs.sh instead

Comment: Unfortunately, just formatting the namenode did not quite work out. I was able to resolve the issue. See my answer to this question. Thanks a lot :)